# Why the error in LWE is sampled from the normal distribution?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe

$$a_1*s+m_1+e_1 = b_1\\\cdots\\ a_n*s+m_n+e_n = b_n$$

The LWE problem is related to finding the solution $s$ to this system, when the $e$ are sampled from the normal distribution. Why the normal distribution?